# OS X - Forbidden - You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/setup on this server

Tags: phpmyadmin, webserver, macos-high-sierra

I have a OS X 10.13 MariaDB server and I would like to be able to search the DB with phpMyAdmin on the local network.  I checked and created a index.php file and php is installed and running on my computer, but when dropping the unzipped phpMyAdmin folder into the /Library/WebServer/Documents/ folder (system web root, not user root) and running localhost/phpMyAdmin/ or localhost/phpMyAdmin/setup, I'm getting:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/setup on this server.
```

I believe my permissions are correct, so is there anything else I should look at?  I searched the stacks here and found a few questions from several years ago, but they had conflicting answers and weren't tailored for OS X, and as I'm new with this I don't know if other OS answers can be applied to my situation.  Thanks.

Edit: So when I enter 'sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf' and go to lines

```
#
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

and comment out and change to

```
AllowOverride all
Require all allowed
```

I get:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /phpmyadmin/ was not found on this server.
```

And my error log (/private/var/log/apache2/) is showing this:

```
[authz_core:error] [pid 2015] [client 127.0.0.1:50343] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/local/phpmyadmin
```

So it looks like it's something with my system web root, but I'm stumped.  If it helps, this is on a new install of 10.13 with no previous access or usage of apache or web server functions that I know of, so it shouldn't have been messed with prior to me trying to get the phpmyadmin folder up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the user webserver folder and following these instructions.  Didn't really solve the system webserver issue I was having, but it is definitely a permissions problem because at least by using the /user/Sites folder I'm good to go now.

https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-12034